# Flutter workmanager: registration a new task with the same name

Tags: flutter, android-workmanager, flutter-workmanager

In the application I need to change a workmanager duration time for the same task.
I'm not sure is it required to cancel this task before?
For instance

```
Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "1",
    simplePeriodicTask,
    initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
    frequency: Duration(minutes: minutes), //20 minutes
);
```

and after some time

```
Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "1",
    simplePeriodicTask,
    initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
    frequency: Duration(minutes: minutes), //40 minutes
);
```

This is the same task. Do I need to cancel it before register a new one *with the same name*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager#existing-work-policy)

**Existing Work Policy**

Indicates the desired behaviour when the same task is scheduled more than once.
The default is KEEP

```
Workmanager.registerOneOffTask("1", "simpleTask", existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.append);
```